# Facebook iOS SDK does not have FBSDKApplicationDelegate class and its methods

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm using in Facebook login in app so I've installed FBSDKLoginKit in my app using cocoapods.

I've followed the Facebook documentation and finished all the steps except this `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`.

The method `application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` is not available in FBSDKLoginKit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've gone through their documentation but they did not specified any thing but I've found the following things in **ChangeLog (on git)**.

- `NS_SWIFT_NAME` was applied where applicable. Most of these changes Xcode can fix automatically.
- The `FBSDK` prefix for UI elements has been replaced with the simpler `FB` prefix.
- The `FBSDK` prefix for all other types has been removed.
  `FBSDKError` is now `CoreError`.

So the class `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` now has been renamed to `ApplicationDelegate` for swift developer.

For objective-c developer this remains same.

**Works For FBSDK version before 5.0.0**

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

**Works For FBSDK version 5.0.0 and later**

```
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

Hope this will help other:) (Before Facebook update their documentation)

**For complete change log for version 5.0.0 [click here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?fbclid=IwAR22QSVPil___E6inVtgfsqw5B95B4kDFIfxRhPJF6hB0Nn-Z1H6l7JdIJc)**

Comment: I might be missing something here, but wasn't the point of prefixing these classes with FBSDK to avoid confusing them with names of our own classes?

Answer (score 7):

If you use Swift you need to use this for FBSDKLoginKit after 5.0 ([source here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?fbclid=IwAR22QSVPil___E6inVtgfsqw5B95B4kDFIfxRhPJF6hB0Nn-Z1H6l7JdIJc#swift-developers)):

```
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else on C#, you have to rename ApplicationDelegate to FBSDKApplicationDelegate